# Is a stateful "Toolbox Class" an antipattern in react?

Tags: reactjs, rest

I have a react application that interacts with a rest interface. The rest interface simply involves listing, filtering, creating and marking simple text entries. Some of these operations require authentication. Many different pages of the application interact with the same parts of that rest interface, so I would like to centralize the access to that interface, basically meaning I would like some sort of object which has methods like .get(filter_params), create(object), mark(object_id), that could be used by all the components to easily interact with the rest interface, handling authentication and errors.
Since the required Auth Info is stored in Context, I was thinking of handling it like this:

```
function DemoEntriesPage(){
    const RMRef = React.createRef();
    const [entries, setEntries] = useState({});
    //Updates the state as the page is loaded, the user scrolls, new entries are made and entries are marked
    const updateState=(newEntries)=>setEntries(Object.assign({},entries,newEntries));

    return  (
        {
        // The RestManager can be used to filter,create and mark entries. 
        // After thats finished, RestManager will call the updateState function 
        // to update the state of its parent component, so it reflects the updated state 
        // RestManager would also consume the AuthContext
        // RestManagers siblings can just call the RMRef functions as needed:
        }
        <RestManager url="api.blabla.com/entries" ref={RMRef} updateState{updateState}/>

        {/*Creates a Form for creating new unmarked entries*/}
        <EntryForm onSubmit={this.RMRef().create} />
        {/*Creates a List view for entries, does the inital load, and pages in new entries as the user scrolls down*/}
        <InfiniteScrollList initialLoad="true" load={this.RMRef().load} entriesRender=
        {
            /*For each loaded entry the rendering can be specified, and a click listener for marking is created*/
            (e)=>
                 <div class="border">
                      <span> {e.text} </span>
                      <span>{e.marked?"marked":"unmarked" </span>
                      <button onclick={()=>this.RMRef().mark(e.id) }  />
                 </div>

        } entries={entries}/>

    )
}
```

But this approach does have a couple problems. First of all, every component that uses RestManager needs to implement a very similar updateState function, since access to the previous state is required in order to update it.
Second it seams like a bad pattern, since it breaks the one directional data flow of react, since it allows sideways communication between components.
So is this a pattern break?

Comment: Your code is tightly coupled to your `RestManager`. Look for state managers like Redux, they will make your life easier by relying on single direction data flow and dispatchable actions.

Comment: I will look into it, thanks